# Pandas read issue, 0xff in position 0

Tags: python, pandas, python-unicode

I 've generated a huge (6G) txt file using a windows command line program (samtools.exe):

`.\samtools.exe mpileup -O bamfile.bam > txtfile.tsv`

The generated file is actually a table separated by tab. When I tried to use pandas.read_table to open it, it gives me:
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte`

When I tried to print the first line of the file, it is like this:
`ÿþAL645882 473 N   1   ^!c I   1`
Everything is normal except the first character. If I read it use `'rb'`, indeed the first character is `0xff`.

I really want this table to be read as a pandas DataFrame, the file is huge, is there anyway I can let python ignore the `0xff` byte? Or simply delete the byte in the file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That looks like a UTF-16 BOM header being misinterpreted:

```
In [25]: with open("tmp.csv", "wb") as fp:
    ...:     fp.write("a,b\n1,2".encode("utf-16"))
    ...: 

In [26]: open("tmp.csv", "rb").read().decode("latin-1")
Out[26]: 'ÿþa\x00,\x00b\x00\n\x001\x00,\x002\x00'

In [27]: print(open("tmp.csv", "rb").read().decode("latin-1"))
ÿþa,b
1,2
```

So you could try interpreting it as UTF-16:

```
In [29]: pd.read_csv("tmp.csv")
[...]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

In [30]: pd.read_csv("tmp.csv", encoding='utf-16')
Out[30]: 
   a  b
0  1  2
```

(There are other hacks you could do if it really *was* only the first two bytes which were causing problems, such as opening a file pointer and reading two bytes, but I suspect as in the above example there are null bytes in the file that aren't immediately obvious, and so it's best to use the right encoding instead.)

Comment: This works!   I guess windows powershell is writing its output as `'UTF-16'` now. I tried another `ls` output in powershell. Notepad++ reports the output file uses `UCS-2 LE BOM` encoding, which is a UTF-16.

Answer (score 1):

It could work for windows7 `spyder3.6`
`data=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Manjeesh/all_state_cancer.csv",encoding='iso-8859-1')`

**UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x85 in position 607: invalid start byte**

Result:

```
:data=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Manjeesh/all_state_cancer.csv",encoding='iso-8859-1')

data
Out[207]: 
     s.no           user.location  \
0       1               Ahmedabad   
1       2   Madhya Pradesh, India   
2       3           Shahdol (MP)    
3       4           Shahdol (MP)    
4       5               Ahmedabad   
5       6        Bengaluru, India   
6       7   Madhya Pradesh, India
```

Comment: You need to explain better how this solves the problem. Is it because that byte is a `iso-8859-1` character?